# Why is my JavaScript function continuing when I have told it to stop while another function runs?

Tags: javascript, function

Not sure why this function is continuing to run. Function a() should always be running except when function b() is running. Function b() is initiated when a button with the class 'btn' is clicked.  I can't figure out why this isn't working. Thanks!

```
    var bActive = false;
    
    if(bActive == false){
        a();
    }
    function a(){
        const toggleGreat = document.querySelector('.great')
        const rawr = document.querySelector('.rawr')

        toggleGreat.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
        rawr.classList.remove('active');
        })
    }
    function b(){
        bActive = true;

        const rawr = document.querySelector('.rawr');
        const paper = document.querySelector('.paper');

        rawr.classList.add('active');
        paper.classList.remove('active')
    }

    btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
        b();
    }
```

Comment: Your function `a` finishes immediately. Why do you think it should be or is running? Please provide code that reproduces your issue. Did you have an infinite loop somewhere?

Comment: if you want to keep `a()` function running, maybe use a `setInterval()`?

Comment: What _exactly_ are you trying to do here?  What problem are you trying to solve in your real application?  I ask this because "always be running" is not how JavaScript works.  You can run stuff in the background with Workers or run stuff asynchronously with Promises and stuff, but JavaScript is generally single-threaded and your code should not try to "keep running" when it doesn't need to.

Comment: What does 'function a should always be running' mean? What does it do?

Comment: Sorry the issue is that a() continues to run, while b() is active. In functionality, b() is putting an image over an image that appears with a mouseover event in a().  I don't want the mouseover event to be active while b() is active, so need a() to stop running.

Comment: Can you show a more representative example of what you mean?  Are you saying that `a()` is being ran inside the `mouseover` and you don't want that event to be ran when `b()` (which is in a `click` event?) is running?

Comment: yup just edited question. Thanks for the help y'all!

Comment: Your mental model of JavaScript is all wrong. Neither function "continues to run", they both run and return immediately. The event handlers bound by `a` remain bound, long after `a` has finished, and the execution of `b` does nothing to affect the event handlers already bound to elements in `a`. If you want the event handlers to change, you either need to unbind them, or test for `bActive` *inside* the event handler itself.

Comment: @meagar ok. That is helpful, how does one, effect event handlers that are already bound in a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions don't "continue to run" the way you describe. Both functions bind event handlers to the DOM and exit immediately. You can't change the functionality of `a` after `a` has already run.

One possible solution is to test whether `bActive` is true *inside* the event handler:

```js
var bActive = false;

const toggleGreat = document.querySelector('.great')
const rawr = document.querySelector('.rawr')
const paper = document.querySelector('.paper');

toggleGreat.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
  if (!bActive) {
    rawr.classList.remove('active');
  }
})

btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  bActive = true;
  rawr.classList.add('active');
  paper.classList.remove('active')
}
```

Comment: This worked! Awesome. Yea, I am obviously new to Javascript and don't quite have the lingo down. Thank you for that clarification. I had been trying conditional statements all over the file, but hadn't thought to add them to the eventListener functions. This makes sense now. Thank you!